# Acknowledging data points below X value in histogram

Tags: r

I'm brand new to R and am looking to move into it for some plots that I will be doing and intend to use ggplot2. I have a dataset which has values from 4-12, but also has around 200 values simply labelled as <4.

I'm trying to put these into a histogram on R but am having difficulty selecting bin sizes. Ideally I would like it to have bins of 1-4, 4-7, 7-10, 10-13

I've been reading documentation and other peoples problems around this issue but am on struggle street. I have a little experience writing automation in AutoHotkey but that's about it for coding. Have not been able to succesfully use the breaks function in order to do what i want

Currently I do not understand how to do this, and simply have a histogram with the bins (single numbers) that R has determined. However i have seen plots produced on R with bins that are intervals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the "breaks" parameter in the hist() function? Or "binwidth" if you're using geom_histogram()

Comment: Hi Bill, yes, i have tried using binwidth in geom_histogram. Unfortunately I don't know how to get it how I would like it. I want my bins on my x axis to show a range of values such as [1-4] but could not figure out how to do this in binwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your value-column will be a character, given that it contains both values and "< 4" entries. I'd suggest using `dplyr` to recode your data and to use a new variable as measure for your bins as follows:

```
library(tidyverse) # loads ggplot2 and dplyr

# some sample data
x <- iris %>%

  # Sample data with '< 4' entries in your value column
  rename(val=Sepal.Length) %>%
  select(val,Species) %>%
  mutate(val=ifelse(val < 4,"< 4",val))

#   val  Species
# 1 5.1  setosa
# 2 4.9  setosa
# 3 4.7  setosa
# 4 4.6  setosa
# 5 5.0  setosa
# 6 5.4  setosa
# ...

# Recoding your data
x <- x %>%
  mutate(indicator=val) %>% # new variable: indicator
  mutate(indicator=ifelse(val == "< 4", "1-3",indicator)) %>%
  mutate(indicator=ifelse(between(round(as.numeric(val),0),4,6), "4-6",indicator)) %>%
  mutate(indicator=ifelse(between(round(as.numeric(val),0),7,9), "7-9",indicator)) %>%
  mutate(indicator=ifelse(between(round(as.numeric(val),0),10,12), "10-12",indicator))

# Plotting
ggplot(x,aes(indicator)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="count") # counting each case in the indicator variable
```

Please note that you may have to adjust your bins as R counts from 1:3, from 4:6 etc. Other programming languages don't include the last number, but R does. By recoding you'll get the right labels on your plot.

[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems when using the code all values that were in the <4 range come up in an NA bin, rather than a 1-3. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if your "<4" matches the exact value you specify in the `ifelse()` call, meaning if there's a space in there like "< 4" or not "<4".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely that you have a character vector, because `<4` cannot be an element in a numeric vector. You need to replace that value and then coerce your vector to numeric. Then you can do a histogram.

```r
x <- sample(c("<4", 5:12), 100, T) # create sample vector
x <- ifelse(x == "<4", "4", x) # replace
x <- as.numeric(x) # coerce
hist(x, breaks = c(0, 4, 7, 10, 13))
```

For future questions, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.